# Добавить в сайт на джумле свои классы

Tags: joomla, классы

При выводе материала он выводится в виде

```
<div class="item-page">

    <h2>О нас</h2>

    <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 14px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut mollis tortor. Donec vitae ipsum lectus.</p>

</div>
```

Как добавить свой класс к заголовку h2 и обернуть текст статьи в див со своим классом?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 2.5

---

Если кому еще интересно, тогда ответ... Идем к файлу: components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php

ищем:

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
<h2>
```

...
И в тег `<h2>` добавляем класс (любой):

```
<h2 class="title_topic">
```

Answer (score 0):

Откройте код соответствующего шаблона, найдите этот блок и добавьте нужный класс. В чём трудность?

Если не знаете как искать, то скачайте весь каталог шаблонов и используйте "умный поиск" по файлам ( я использую для этого Sublime Text 2). 
Фраза для поиска, например, "<div class="item-page">".

Comment: При чем тут это? заголовок выводится в теге h2, мне нужно добавить к нему класс. В шаблоне у меня прописано <jdoc:include type="component" /> и все, нет там никаких тегов.

Comment: /templates

Рекомендую ознакомиться с общей структурой Joomla'ы. 
http://joomla-book.ru/development/creating-templates/files-and-folders-template

Comment: у меня есть все нужные файлы в шаблоне http://i.imgur.com/G8MGufh.png , у меня прописаны стилевые свойства в подключенном файле стилей, мне нужно добавить СВОИ КЛАССЫ к ТЕГАМ, которые автоматически генерирует джумла.

Comment: надо тогда смотреть код, который их генерирует и "допиливать" его своими классами.